# Вывод из базы данных в RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Я новичок, и мне нужен Ваш совет.

```
class MapController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end
end
```

Вьюха:

```
<header class="row">
  <div class="col-4"><h4>Имя Фамилия</h4></div>
  <div class="col-4"><h4>Начинающий <span>1203</span></h4></div>
  <div class="col-4"><h4>Ваши очки <span>23</span></h4></div>
</header>
<section class="map__map">
  <% @tasks.each do |t| %>
    <svg class="map__task">
      <circle r="30" cx="30" cy="30"></circle>
      <text fill="#ccc" x="21" y="40" font-size="30"><%= t.id %></text>
    </svg>
  <% end %>
</section>
<div class="map__task-window">
  <span class="task-window__close btn btn-danger"></span>
  <h5 class="task-window__title">Название</h5>
  <div class="task-window__description">Описание</div>
  <div class="task-window__container">
    <div class="task-window__profit">+102 к опыту</div>
    <div class="task-window__rate">3 очка требуется</div>
    <button class="task-window__button btn btn-success">Начать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на элемент `map__task` обновлялись данные в `map__task-window`.
Я себе это представляю так: при клике на элемент вызывается функция в js, она определяет id и ищет по нему в базе данных параметры, после чего записывает их в соответствующие данные в окне.
Пока что js не делает ничего кроме появления и исчезновения окна.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var durationTaskWindow = 100;
    var taskWindow = $('.map__task-window');
    $('.task-window__close').click(function () {
        taskWindow.fadeOut(durationTaskWindow);
    });
    $('.map__task').click(function (e) {
        taskWindow.fadeIn(durationTaskWindow);
    })
});
```

Подскажите, где можно узнать об этом побольше или варианты решения. Не получается найти

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант решения - использовать AJAX для получения данных при помощи API на сервере. Современные версии рельс вроде как позволяют без особых проблем JSON возвращать. Вот и получайте еще AJAX'ом и обрабатывайте как нужно.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это делается. Можете подсказать какой-нибудь ресурс, где можно узнать все это

Comment: Про построение JSON API читайте здесь: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html, про AJAX, например, тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro. Насчет первой ссылки: там речь идет больше о построении API-only приложения, но оттуда нетрудно будет почерпнуть основные принципы и "расширить" уже имеющееся приложение.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Кстати, если я ничего не путаю, то в современных версиях рельс они сами отдают JSON (если вы в контроллере определите его формат, разумеется), при запросе, оканчивающемся на `.json`. Например `app.com/home` ответит вам обычным набором - HTML, JS, Asserts, вот это вот все, а `app.com/home.json` вернет JSON ответ (повторюсь, если в контроллере определен формат этого ответа).